# How to get different types of responseType in angular from asp.net core web API method

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular6

for this operation, we wrote one web API in asp.net core 2.0 and we returning two different types of response if condition executed successfully it will return zip file as a response to the angular and we will save at Machine.

and if the condition is false it will send the JSON to the angular so here we want show PopUp to the user  along with the JSON data

but we keep  [responseType: "arraybuffer"] in the angular application  so for both condition we are getting "arraybuffer" in response

```
//asp.net core web api code
// code wrote for two different return type 

if(condition == true )
{
  return File(zipBytes, "application/zip", "Data.zip");
}
else
{
  return Json(new Response { Code=111,Data= 
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList)});
}
```

//********************************************************************//

```
//Angular 6 Code
//Code wrote for getting a response as a zip in the angular service file 

postWithZip(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${path}`, JSON.stringify(body), {
        headers: this.setHeaders({ multipartFormData: false, zipOption: true }),
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
      })
      .catch(this.formatErrors);
  }
```

as you can see in the above angular code it handles the zip file response but  not working for JSON response.

So How we can achieve both scenarios in this case?

//*************************************************************//

```
// this is the Method we wrote in asp.net 
[Route("GetAcccountWithCredits")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetAccountWithCredtis([FromBody]AccountsWithCreditsRequest tempRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                BusinessHelper businessHelper = new BusinessHelper(_hostingEnvironment, _iconfiguration, _smtpDetails, _options, _dbSettings);
                //Get data from stored procedure
                var accountsWithCredits = businessHelper.getAccountsWithCredtis(tempRequest);

                //Delete existing files from Excel folder
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\Excels\\Accounts with Credit Balances");
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //Convert stored procedure response to excel
                dt = businessHelper.ConvertToCSV("Garages", accountsWithCredits, _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\" + _iconfiguration["CSVFilePath"]);
                List<string> myList = new List<string>();
                if (dt.TableName == "codeDoesNotExits")
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        myList.Add((string)row[0]);
                    }
                }
                if (myList.Count == 0)
                {
                    //Create List of excel files details(name, path)
                    List<FileObjectDeails> listOfFiles = new List<FileObjectDeails>();
                    FileObjectDeails garadesList = new FileObjectDeails();
                    garadesList.FileName = _iconfiguration["GaragesFileName"];
                    garadesList.FilePath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "\\" + _iconfiguration["CSVFilePath"] + "\\" + _iconfiguration["GaragesFileName"];
                    listOfFiles.Add(garadesList);


                    if (tempRequest.EmailId != "")
                    {
                        string subject = _iconfiguration["AccountsWithCreditEmailSubject"];
                        string body = _iconfiguration["AccountsWithCreditEmailBody"];
                        //Send Email with files as attachment
                        businessHelper.SendEmail(listOfFiles, tempRequest.EmailId, subject, body);
                    }

                    //Convert files into zip format and return
                    byte[] zipBytes;
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                        {
                            foreach (var attachment in listOfFiles)
                            {
                                var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(attachment.FileName);

                                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(attachment.FilePath, FileMode.Open))
                                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                                {
                                    fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        zipBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    return File(zipBytes, "application/zip", "GarageData.zip");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new Response { Code = 111, Status = "Got Json", Message = "Fount Account Code which is not present in XML File", Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList) });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: in .net code , which type is your method returning  ? ( can you show please the full method code )

Comment: a return type of method is "IActionResult"

Comment: hey, @MohamedAliRACHID I just added the .net method please check it

Comment: A method with two different return types has an invalid specification. Method return types should be invariant. Just because you *can* do something does not mean it is smart to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for accepting both type of response we need to make the change in angular service code as below

```
 postWithZip(
    path: string,
    body: Object = {}
  ): Observable<HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${path}`, JSON.stringify(body), {
        headers: this.setHeaders({ multipartFormData: false, zipOption: true }),
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
      })
      .catch(this.formatErrors);
  }
```

and then we can identify both responses using contentType as follow

```
   res => {
        if (res.headers.get("content-type") == "application/zip") {
          *//Write operation you want to do with the zip file*
        } else {
          var decodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(
            null,
            new Uint8Array(res.body)
          );
          var obj = JSON.parse(decodedString);
         *//Write operation you want to done with JSON*
        }
      }
```